# Jquery DateTime Picker doesnot display with page css

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

have download Jquery DatePicker and try to add to my View.
But the DatePicker only work fine when I remove all my page css file

If I keep both of them, the DatePicker display very strange with a small rectangle
I am using Jquery 1.8.2 and Jquery-ui 1.8.24

I think the main reason is that there is some duplication between css in my file with the css in the DatePicker
Please help me to solve it
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to download firebug,if you haven't it already, and select the datapicker.
In this way the firebug console display you on the right column the CSS style related to the selected item,here you can disable the CSS property and see wich one cause you the problem.
Also be sure that you have the jquery ui images in the correct folder

Comment: Yes, I used it, but there are many tags using z-index, it is impossible to check and replace all of them, because I use the css from another design, it is more than 500 lines. Is there any way to config the datetimepicker on javascript?

Comment: Thanks Dheed, I do it manualy to set all z-index on my design css, and it works ok now

Comment: If I don't remember wrong there is jquery plugin that set z-index automatically,otherwise you should loop troughs the body elements